# Centering an ImageView using addContentView

Tags: android

I am trying to create a LinearLayout and an ImageView inside it through code. I want to use addContentView in particular because the android code is for a Unity3D plugin and using setContentView overlaps the game but setContentView does work. However using addContentView places the image at the center BUT it is at the very top of the screen. I want it at screen center.

```
   LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    //layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    //layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((100),( 100));
    imageViewParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

    ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    iv.setLayoutParams(imageViewParams);
    iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    iv.setImageResource(drawable_spinner);

    layout.addView(iv);

    addContentView(layout, layoutParams);
```

As you can see, I have already tried setting the gravity to layoutParams and setting that to the layout as  well but nothing changes.

Can somebody please tell me what I'm missing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Check the gravity of the layout already existing in your activity. Sounds like it's set to top-left instead of center. Also if the image view is the only thing in your dynamic layout, you may want to consider just not using a layout and add only the image view.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point(); display.getSize(size);
Integer screenWidth=size.x; 
Integer screenHeight=size.y;
```

This is how I measure the screen. Your imageView should be 100x100 on every device. So you should be able to set it like so...

```
imageView.setLeft((screenWidth/2)-50);
imageView.setTop((screenHeight/2)-50);
```

Comment: I don't have access to the default layout. It would have been so much easier if I had. So if I want to add just the imageView, do I give the first parameter to addContentView as imageView ?

Comment: How about measuring the screen and manually setting your image in the center by x-y coordinates?

Comment: I tried that as well. But for some reason, it was off the center by a small amount. 
And I tried adding only the imageView using addContentView, it got placed at top left.

Comment: (screenWidth/2-imageWidth/2, screenHeight/2-imageHeight/2) This coordinate should put your image right in the center.

Comment: but the imageWidth won't be the same on all devices right ? Won't android actually change it based on screen resolution and pixel density ?

Could you tell me how you would calculate imageWidth and imageheight ? 

To place it at the center, I just used window manager's getWidth and getHeight and divided by 2

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code to below:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((100), (100));

ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
iv.setImageResource(drawable_spinner);
layout.addView(iv, imageViewParams);

addContentView(layout, layoutParams);
```

Comment: I even tried MATCH_PARENT for layoutParams. It didn't make a difference.

Comment: @Aadithya What do you mean? I tested it with above code and it is perfectly centered in the screen. You are adding your linear layout to already existing layout. Maybe the parent layout is having some width/height restrictions. If you change last line to `setContentView(layout, layoutParams);` you will see it is centered.

Comment: setContentView is not what I want to do because this is on top of a game. So setContentView blocks out the game and everything around the image will be black. setContentView does work but I have to do it using addContentView. I'll be more than happy if there are other approaches

Comment: Well, if you have some parent layout which does not allow your linear layout to expand to screen size or cannot be centered, you may do it with a `AlertDialog`. But this will be another question.

Comment: I was originally  doing all of this inside another class that extended Dialog. Even then I wasn't able to center it. For some reason, it was slightly below the center and I had to set a margin to push it upwards but the amount by which I need to push it upwards varied from device to device and I discarded.

Comment: Maybe your bitmap (`drawable_spinner)` is having some transparent border on top and that's why it looks displaced.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82641/discussion-between-aadithya-and-dimitar-genov).

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
`MATCH_PARENT` everywhere possible and `weight=1` for the imageview.

But as long as we know nothing about the surrounding  views we can't give you a definite solution.

Comment: I have no clue how the default layout is setup.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
    RelativeLayout rootLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    rootLayout.setLayoutParams( new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size, size);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    ivOne = new ImageView(this);
    ivOne.setImageResource(drawable_spinner);
    ivOne.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    ivOne.setLayoutParams(params);
    rootLayout.addView(ivOne);
    addContentView(rootLayout,new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

if something other than ScaleType.FIT_XY is used, it actually crops the image.